# Arduino Uno won't connect when using USB-C to USB adapter

Tags: arduino-uno, usb

So I just got my first Arduino which is an Arduino Uno. I have a newer MacBook Air which doesn't have any USB ports so I thought I'd just use one of those USB-C to USB adapters.

I plugged it in and then searched for the Board in the Tools > Port menu. It was nowhere to be seen, only the `/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port` showed up.

To be clear, the Arduino did show signs of connectivity, it just didn't show up under the Port list. I'm also not 100% sure if it's an Arduino Uno since the company I bought it from said I should select Arduino/Genuino Uno in the Board menu which isn't an option anymore.

Is it a problem with my Arduino, my Laptop or my adapter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it is not original, and it uses different usb-serial chip than the original one. Popular converters for Arduino Uno clones are CH340 and CP2104. You may try to install the driver for these 2 chips.

Comment: It now shows up in the Ports tab after installing the CH340 driver. Thanks a lot!